# C# Split string every other comma on long string

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
string  a =  "Stuff, another thing, random stuff, snuff, Pigs are wierd, sick, Cats are dangerous, they will kill you, Cows produce milk, but horses don't"
```

So my goal is to retrieve a string that looks like this

```
string output =  "Stuff, another thing
                  Random stuff, snuff
                  Pigs are wierd, sick
                  Cats are dangerous, they will kill you
                  Cows produce milk, but horses don't"
```

Tried to do it with regex but couldn't really get it to group up correctly if the string would have been longer in a good way.

```
string[] output = Regex.Split(a, "^([^,]+(?:,[^,]+){1})");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. You should not use the Split function of Regex. You should use Matches.

```
        string a = "Stuff, another thing, random stuff, snuff, Pigs are wierd, sick, Cats are dangerous, they will kill you, Cows produce milk, but horses don't";
        var output = Regex.Matches(a, "[^,]+,[^,]+,*");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(Match item in output)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(item.Value.Trim(','));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Split it along all commas and then reassemble into comma-separated pairs.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string  a =  "Stuff, another thing, random stuff, snuff, Pigs are wierd, sick, Cats are dangerous, they will kill you, Cows produce milk, but horses don't";
        string[] splittedStrings = a.Split(new[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        for (var i = 0; i < splittedStrings.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(splittedStrings[i*2] + ", " + splittedStrings[i*2 + 1]);
        }

        if(splittedStrings.Length % 2 == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(splittedStrings[splittedStrings.Length-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question mentions that they need every other comma, so all commans for even indexes

Comment: "comma-separated pair" = "item1, item2". As a sidenote, the question does not specify whether a comma is expected if the last index is even.

Answer (score 0):

Here a way doing it via c#

1. Split the string and leave the ',' on even idexes so 0 2 4 would still contain the comma

   var splittedWithComasOnEvenIndexes = a.Split(',').Select((value, index) => value + (index % 2 == 0 ? "," : ""));
2. The join the string

   var result = string.Join("", splittedWithComasOnEvenIndexes);

The result is as follows 
**

> Stuff, another thing random stuff, snuff Pigs are wierd, sick Cats are
>   dangerous, they will kill you Cows produce milk, but horses don't

**

Answer (score 0):

I would also split and reassemble, but I would make a more robust solution to handle no commas and odd number of pairs.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitGroup(this string input, char delimiter)
    {
        var fields = input.Split(delimiter);
        var items = new List<string>();
        var enumerator = fields.GetEnumerator();

        //this will handle no commas, and not and even number of pairs
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var first = enumerator.Current;
            var hasNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
            var second = hasNext ? enumerator.Current : "";

            items.Add(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", first, hasNext ? "," : "", second));
        }

        return items;
    }
```

To call the extension method:

```
var a = "Stuff, another thing, random stuff, snuff, Pigs are wierd, sick, Cats are dangerous, they will kill you, Cows produce milk, but horses don't, frogs";

var items = a.SplitGroup(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you drop in the "System.Interactive" NuGet package then you can do this:

```
var result =
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        a.Split(',').Buffer(2).Select(x => String.Join(",", x)));
```